# How to upgrade Safari from v11 to v12, not v13?

Tags: macos, safari, upgrade

Currently Safari 13 is the latest version.

I'm running Safari 11, but want to upgrade just to 12 (12.1).

https://support.apple.com/downloads/safari only lists Safari 13.

Is there any place where I can find Safari 12 (12.1)?

Comment: Based on what I found there is no way to download recent versions of Safari separately. I only [found a page](https://support.apple.com/downloads/safari) with Safari [5.1.10](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1569) (September 2013) and [Safari 1.2](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL612) (February 2004) which is curious but completely useless for you.

Comment: (And to my deep disappointment it seems impossible to install them on macOS Catalina: 5.1.10 requires Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6 and 1.2 refuses to install without explanation. I saw a video of Windows upgrade from 3.1 to 7 and at least by the time of Windows XP they still managed to run apps from 3.1.)